# Returning distinct prioritizing results with order by

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
Name varchar, Value int, Active bit
-----------------------------------
'Name1',1,1
'Name2',2,1
'Name1',3,0
'Name2',4,0
'Name3',1,1
'Name4',1,1
```

I want to return where `Active` is anything but prioritize when it's `0` so I want to return this:

```
'Name1',3
'Name2',4
'Name3',1
'Name4',1
```

I tried this, but get an error to include `Active` in my return statement

```
Select Distinct Name, Value From Table Order by Active
```

So I tried this:

```
Select Distinct Name, Value, Active From Table Order by Active
```

But now it returns all the rows.  I would like to prioritize `where Active = 0` in the distinct results but since it requires I put `Active` in the return statement makes this complicated.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little confusing, but if I'm understanding it correctly, you need to use a `group by` statement:

```
select name,
  max(case when active = 0 then value end) value
from yourtable
group by name
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/93c89/1)

---

With your edits, you can use `coalesce` and still get it to work:

```
select name, coalesce(max(case when active = 0 then value end), max(value)) value
from yourtable
group by name
```

- [More Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/86d50/4)

Comment: Sorry for any confusion, see my edit at the top to clarify when I need to return all the rows.

Comment: @ZeeTee -- Give that a go.  The key is adding `coalesce` to get the values that aren't marked `active=0` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can order by fields not contained in the select clause

```
Select Name, Value 
From Table
ORDER BY Active, Name, Value
```

But you cannot use `SELECT DISTINCT` at the same time.

If you use "select distinct" there is the possibility that some rows will be discarded, when this happens there is no longer any viable relationship retained between [Active] and the "distinct" rows. So if using select distinct, and you need to order by [Active], then [Active] MUST be in the select clause.

Comment: I need to return both, but prioritize it when it's `0`

Comment: @ZeeTee: Both "what"?

Comment: that is NOT what your question states (look at "I want to return this")

Comment: sorry, I have a newer version, please refresh it. The problem is "select distinct"

Comment: But that defeats the purpose, since I can't return duplicate names.

Comment: "I hate distinct", see http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/markc/archive/2008/11/11/60752.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this:

```
create table #t(
    Active int         not null,
    Name   varchar(10) not null,
    Value  int         not null,

    primary key clustered (Active desc,Name,Value)
);

insert #t(Active,Name,Value)
select Active,Name,Value from [Table];

select Name, Value
from #t;
go
```

yields as desired:

```
Name       Value
---------- -----------
Name1      1
Name2      2
Name3      1
Name4      1
Name1      3
Name2      4
```

Comment: I need to return both `Active=0` & `Active=1`, but prioritize it when it's `Active=0`

Comment: @ZeeTee: What does that mean?

Comment: It means I can't restrict the statement to where `Active=0` , see my edit.

Comment: Woah, thats complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't delete the post b/c of the other answers, but here is answer I was looking for in case anyone else was wondering.

<s>SELECT Distinct Name,Value FROM Table WHERE Active = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Distinct Name,Value FROM Table a WHERE Active = 1 AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM Table a2 WHERE a2.Active = 0 AND a2.Name = a.Name
    )</s>

### Review @Sgeddes 's answer for a better solution.

Thanks to everyone for their help.

Comment: This won't return your expected results though?  It returns `Name1` twice?

Comment: I just updated it and it works. Unless you have a better way to do it?

Comment: Take a look at my edited solution.  While this approach will work, I think you'd have much better performance with a single `group by` clause.